# sdkman List is Empty for Java, Scala, Etc

Tags: java, sdkman

When using sdkman on Mac M2 my list command is empty (screenshot attached). I believe this is connected to sdk install which then results with the issue below.

I have ran both `sdk selfupdate force` and `sdk update` to no avail

Install command

```
❯ sdk install java

Stop! java 21.0.2-tem is not available. Possible causes:
 * 21.0.2-tem is an invalid version
 * java binaries are incompatible with your platform
 * java has not been released yet
```

Version

```
❯ sdk version

SDKMAN!
script: 5.18.2
native: 0.4.3
```

sdk list should provide available installations I can make